# C++ variables not changing as intended

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on an object oriented project for C++ programming.
I have created a few objects:

```
int main()
{
    Address address1 = Address("7732","cambie street","vancouver","BC","v5p3r3");
    Author author1 = Author("Joe","Howe","joehow@hotmail.ca");
    Publisher publisher1("candy",address1);
    Book book1 = Book("sprite",author1,publisher1,"1995");
 return 0;
}
```

and here are my 4 object constructors

```
Address::Address(string number, string name, string c, string crty, string pCode){
    streetNumber = number;
    streetName = name;
    city = c;
    country = crty;
    postalCode = pCode;
}
Book::Book(string newTitle, Author author1,Publisher pub, string y){
    ISBN++;
    bookISBN = ISBN;
    title = newTitle;
    a = author1;
    authorCount = 1;
    d = pub;
    year = y;
}
Author::Author(string fN, string lN, string e){

    firstName = fN;
    lastName = lN;
    email = e;
}
Publisher::Publisher(string n, Address x){
    name = n;
    a = x;
}
```

when i call these functions in the main

```
cout << book1.getPublisher().getAddress().getCity() << endl;
book1.getPublisher().getAddress().set("washington",Address::CITY);
cout << book1.getPublisher().getAddress().getCity() << endl;
```

not sure if these are allowed in c++ i've done them in java,

i've also tried separating them and it would give me the desired results,

so my question becomes is this format allowed in c++ and if so what am i doing wrong.

my result displays

```
vancouver
vancouver
```

but my desired result would be

```
vancouver
washington
```

these are my get/set functions

```
Address Publisher::getAddress(){
    return a;
}


Publisher Book::getPublisher(){
    return d;
}
void Address::set(string value , int number){
switch(number)
{
    case STREET_NUMBER:
        streetNumber = value;break;
    case STREET_NAME:
        streetName = value;break;
    case CITY:
        city = value;break;
    case COUNTRY:
        country = value;break;
    case POSTAL_CODE:
        postalCode = value;break;


  }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please get a book on C++. Your problem is that you are using things learned from Java in C++. Since these two languages have a radically different object model, your code fails. Nikita explained some of it (copying returnvalues), but there's more to it, hence the suggestion to read a good book.

Comment: Agree with @UlrichEckhardt;  You should read about pointers and references and understand what they are and how to use them... as this is much closer to what other languages work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAddress()` returns a copy of `Address` object, so you change copy, not `Address` field in `Publisher`.

To fix the problem `getAddress()` should return reference:

```
Address& Publisher::getAddress()
{
    return a;
}
```

Probably you need to redesign your object hierarchy, because [returning references (pointers) to internals is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005514/is-returning-references-of-member-variables-bad-pratice).

Comment: return a reference

Comment: okay would this also apply with getPublisher() and getCity()
Edit: oh ya it works thank you very much

Comment: BTW: I think in Java it'll change even `address1` object instance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create the method

```
Book::setAddress(Address ads)
```

or either use pointer/reference to modify it's value.
Otherwise you'll just get a copy of it

Answer (score 0):

In the Java everything is reference. In C++ is not.

There are so many copies of your objects, that you can't easily do what you want without using pointers.