# Problems with getters and setters in C++

Tags: c++, class, getter-setter, access-modifiers, modifier

I have a problem with my getters and setters in C++. I implemented a Queue, I also implememented a class Process. My queue saves processes. My class Process has two attributes: "Identifier" and "Time" and also has setters and getters. I set 80 as its Time. The problem then is that I want to modify the time to 50 and it doesn't change. I think that the problem is the Queue, but I don't know where. Heres is my fragment of code

```
Queue<Process> process;
Process x;
x.setIdentifier("Hi");
x.setTime(80);
process.enqueue(x);
process.getElementFront().setTime(50);
process.print();
```

Here is my Queue code:

```
class Queue{
private:
    int size;
    Node <L> *front;
public:
     .
     .
     .
    //front()
    
    L getElementFront() const{
        return this->front->getElement();
    }
```

Here is my Node code:

```
class Node{
private:
    L elem;
    Node *next;
public:
    .
    .
    .
    L getElement() {
        return this->elem;
    }
```

This is my Process Class:

```
class Process{
private:
    string identifier;
    int time;
public:
    Process(){
        identifier = "";
        time = 0;
    }
    string getIdentifier(){
        return identifier;
    }
    int getTime(){
        return time;
    }
    void setTime(int time){
        this->time = time;
    }
    void setIdentifier(string identifier){
        this->identifier = identifier;
    }
    
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Process &p);
    
  };
  ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Process &p){
    o<<"Identifier: "<<p.identifier<<"\n";
    o<<"Time:"<<p.time<<"\n";
  return o;
  }
```

The output of the first code is: Time = 80. I should be Time = 50, but time wasn't modified.

Comment: Your function returns a copy of the value, not a reference, so any modification of that value doesn't affect the original.

Comment: How can I make it to return the original?

Comment: Do you know what references are, and how to use them?

Comment: I made this function:
L getElementByReference() {
   L *pointer = &this->elem;
   return *pointer;
  }

Comment: it still doesnt work ...}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ variables not changing as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870457/c-variables-not-changing-as-intended)

Comment: getElementFront() returns a copy that setTime() modifies then the copy is thrown away. Then you print the process with original time. The duplicate in the link above this comment explains this.

Comment: Yeees, JaMiT, It worked finally. Thank you all of you for helping me to learn something new

Answer (score 2):

I believe your function "getElementFront" returns a copy of your element, So your queue will never be affected. You can write a function like "setElementFront(int)" to affect the element directly or something like this.

Comment: Confirmation: It *does* return a copy (L) of the node’s value.