# Returning Composite object of composite pattern doesn't return the whole object

Tags: c++, vector, composite

I created a composite pattern with Component, Leaf and Composite Classes, where only the Composite Class has both a member variable vector  and add method:

```
void add(Component *a);
vector < Component * > children;
```

In a separate class B, I created a method getComponent() to return a Composite member variable

```
Class B: public A
{
    Composite m_Comp;
    public:
    Composite * getComponent() 
    {
        Leaf myLeaf1;
        Leaf myLeaf2;
        Composite myComp1;
        myComp1.add(&Leaf1)
        myComp1.add(&Leaf2)
        Leaf myLeaf3;
        m_Comp.add(&myComp1);
        m_Comp.add(&myLeaf3);

        m_Comp.inspect()   

        return &m_Comp;
    }
};
```

when I inspect mypCompCheck it looks right, but when I retrieve it (?) from main:

```
A* myA;
AuxClass myAuxObject;
myA=myAuxObject.returnReferenceToClassBObject();
Composite * mypComp=myA->getComponent(); 
mypComp->inspect()
```

mypComp is not the same object. Is it wrong the way I think to return it?

Here my alternative way, after reading [Is returning references of member variables bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8005514/5973613), but still not working...

```
Class B: public A
    {
    public:        
        Composite m_Comp;
        setComponent() 
        {
            Leaf myLeaf1;
            Leaf myLeaf2;
            Composite myComp1;
            myComp1.add(&Leaf1)
            myComp1.add(&Leaf2)
            Leaf myLeaf3;
            m_Comp.add(&myComp1);
            m_Comp.add(&myLeaf3);
            m_Comp.inspect();
        }
    };
```

and in main

```
A* myA;
AuxClass myAuxObject;
myA=myAuxObject.returnReferenceToClassBObject();
myA=myAuxObject.m_Comp.inspect();
```

when I inspect the object into the get method, it correctly shows all its components, including nested ones. When I do it in main, I see the myComp1 inside m_Comp as a Component instead than as a Composite.

Because of that, and because similar design with std objects (instead of Composite ones) work, I wondered if there was possibly something wrong in how I work with composite, more than in how I'm returning the member variable...  I mean, I'm adding by references those components through the add method, and they are then limited in scope?

Thus, I replaced all the local variables with member ones, and it works...

```
Class A
    {
        Leaf m_Leaf1;
        Leaf m_Leaf2;
        Composite myComp1;
        Leaf myLeaf3;

        public:
        Composite m_Comp;
        setComponent();
       {
            m_Comp1.add(&m_Leaf1)
            m_Comp1.add(&m_Leaf2)
            m_Comp.add(&m_Comp1);
            m_Comp.add(&m_Leaf3);
            m_Comp.inspect();
       }
};
```

and in main

```
A myA;
myA.m_Comp.inspect();
```

I got some fruitful learning, thanks to your hints and related searches.

Comment: Note that all of those variables will go out of scope once the function exits.

Comment: In `main`, you're calling a member function on a `null_ptr` essentially.

Comment: After looking at this more, it seems like you might need to learn about C++ and pointers. Specifically, I'd recommend learning about `[new]https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/new)` and its related keywords (like `delete`).

Comment: yes, I'm working on it, I miss some basics.  But still, I don't get why other implementations I did worked, differing only in the non-Composite nature of their returned objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises in main(). You are creating empty object of type `A*` which points to `nullptr`. Then you are tying to call member function of `myA`, which in this case points to nothing, try to initialize it correctly, then call you member function via `myA`.

Comment: Thanks Sargis. I thought, as m_Comp is a member variable of A, that it would not go out of scope. I see I have to work on some basic stuff

Comment: You are returning `Composite m_Comp;` as  `Component * getComponent() ` maybe here is the problem?

Comment: That's my mistake sorry!

Comment: I tried, I replaced Component with Composite (and updated the text of my question) but the two objects are still different...

Comment: Thanks Sargis, I modified the code, B is a Class derived by an abstract class A. is the new version right in relation to your observation?