# Mutator returning by reference

Tags: c++, getter-setter

Is there anything wrong with mutating a private variable by returning it by reference? Like:

```
int& data() {
    return _data;
}
```

It allows you to do weird things like:

```
std::cout << (test.data() = 60) << std::endl; // 60
print_int((test.data() = 70)); // 70
test.data() = 50;
```

I've seen different verbose variations of getter-setters and this seems streamlined, although I get the nagging feeling that it's frowned upon.

Comment: Some straightforward legitimate uses: to provide an index operation that works naturally like many standard containers do; to provide a method to return a reference to a stream-like object to use for logging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can I expose private members when I return a reference from a public member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706788/why-can-i-expose-private-members-when-i-return-a-reference-from-a-public-member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 'private variable' I assume you mean 'private member to the class.'  It's perfectly legal, although often (but not always) bad design.

Your examples of how you might use it certainly are dubious, and raise the question of what the getter method actually buys you for access control or encapsulation.

Suppose you do want to pass something back to the caller that allows it to mutate the object's internal state other than through that object's own methods, possibly because you need a different interface for some reason.  A better approach would be to return a reference to an adaptor object that lets you manipulate that state indirectly.

Why do that?  If you need more than one sort of interface to the same state, you can encapsulate that state in a "core" object, and have it provide adaptors with alternate interfaces if other objects/code expect different interfaces for mutating that same state.

Because you keep an 'object wall' and never expose your internal state directly, you are still free to change your representation within the object.  And, you can still enforce whatever invariants and constraints your object requires.  You just need to update the adaptor class when you update your object.  You need not inspect any of the callers that grabbed a reference to that adaptor.

An example of that alternate pattern:

```
class barney_adaptor : public barney_interface
{
    // ... 
  public:
    barney_adaptor( int &intref_ ) : intref( intref_ ) { }

    // ... code that implements barney_interface
};

class fred
{
     int m_internal;

     barney_adaptor m_barney_adaptor;

   public:
     fred() : m_barney_adaptor( m_internal ) { };


     //... bunch of stuff elided
     barney_adaptor &as_barney() { return m_barney_adaptor; }
};
```

Such an approach doesn't always make sense; often it's better just to inherit from whatever interfaces you're expected to implement.  That's not always practical, though, especially if the various interfaces you need to support have method names that clash.

It's rarely a good idea, though, to provide mutable access to private members.  It's not very different from just moving the private member to the `public:` side of the class.